# How do I echo a div using SQL table row ID as ID for the div?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this PHP code, which fetches data from my SQL database called "comments".
This code prints out every comment in the table:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id,name,email,number,text FROM comments";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<strong>ID:</strong><br>  " . $row["id"] . "<br>";
        echo "<strong>Navn:</strong><br>  " . $row["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "<strong>Email:</strong><br> " . $row["email"] . "<br>";
        echo "<strong>Nummer:</strong><br> " . $row["number"] . "<br>";
        echo "<strong>Melding:</strong><br> " . $row["text"] . "<br><br><br>";
    }
    echo '<div class = "white_line_comments"></div>';
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

This has worked fine so far, everything prints as it's supposed to.
Then I decided I wanted a way to give each individual comment some sort of identification to make them unique. I tried putting each single comment into its own div, using the SQLtable row id as id for the div.

However, when I try to access my webpage now, it tells me the website doesn't work (HTTP Error 500).

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id,name,email,number,text FROM comments";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "
<div class='$row[' id'].'>";
echo "<strong>ID:</strong><br>  " . $row["id"] . "<br>";
echo "<strong>Navn:</strong><br>  " . $row["name"] . "<br>";
echo "<strong>Email:</strong><br> " . $row["email"] . "<br>";
echo "<strong>Nummer:</strong><br> " . $row["number"] . "<br>";
echo "<strong>Melding:</strong><br> " . $row["text"] . "<br><br><br>";
echo '</div>';
}
    echo '
<div class="white_line_comments"></div>';
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Any ideas on this? I guess I must've done something wrong when including the `div`, but I can't figure out what!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in this line after starting while loop:

```
echo "<div class ='$row['id'].'>";
```

It should be

```
echo "<div class ='". $row['id'] ."'>";
```

You should also configure your web server/hosting/localhost to throw a PHP error.

Read this if you are on localhost or your own server:
[How can I make PHP display the error instead of giving me 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er)

Read this if you are using shared hosting: [How do I displaying details of a PHP internal server error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751591/how-do-i-displaying-details-of-a-php-internal-server-error)

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help. Please choose my answer if you think it helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "<div class ='$row['id'].'>";
```

First line in while loop should look like this

```
echo "<div class = '".$row['id']."'>";
```

or

```
echo "<div class = '$row['id']'>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed different apostrophe, try this:

```
echo "<div class ='" . $row['id'] . "'>";
```